# Installing Git on Cygwin says Makefile recipe failed

Tags: git, cygwin

I have installed Cygwin correctly since I followed the [Ruby on Rails tutorial guide](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning#sec-install_git). I am stuck when I try to install Git by executing the "make" command, as it returns this:

```
    LINK git-credential-store.exe
    /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lz                                            
    /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -liconv                                       
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    Makefile:2040: recipe for target 'git-credential-store.exe' failed
    make: *** [git-credential-store.exe] Error 1´
```

It was already giving me problems with the "zlib" library headers as it was not locating its directory although I had it installed when I ran Cygwin. I managed to solve it by searching the missing .h files wich were somewhere in the Cygwin directory and I placed them in the Git install location and that worked.

Comment: Not an answer, but do you really need cygwin? The native Git Bash tool is pretty awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That section send you to "[Installing on Windows](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git#Installing-on-Windows)" which points to **[msysgit](http://msysgit.github.io/)**.
Unzip a [portable archive of Git](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=2&q=portable&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount) anywhere you want, add it to your %PATH% and you have Git up and running.

No need for Cygwin to install Git or Ruby.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm going to do the installation all over again and try one of those git files. I'll get back to you if I run into any issues. Thank you once again